# ADFS endpoint issue

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, adfs

I am trying to access crm 2011 org like:

```
using (OrganizationService service = new OrganizationService("CrmConnection"))
{
}
```

The connectionString looks like:

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="CrmConnection" connectionString="Server=https://OurDomainName.OurDomainName.com;Username=TheUser;Password=ThePass" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

When I run the code it throws below error:

```
There was no endpoint listening at 
http://adfslogin.OurDomainName.com/adfs/services/trust/13/username 
that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action.
```

Please note that I can access the URL in IE using the same credentials as specified in the web.config.

Can someone point out what I am missing which is causing the issue?

Comment: Guide for 2013, still valid (nothing changed between versions) http://blogs.msdn.com/b/niran_belliappa/archive/2014/01/16/step-by-step-configuring-crm-2013-internet-facing-deployment-ifd.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to this: http://www.powerobjects.com/blog/2014/04/22/error-adfsifd-url-dynamics-crm/

It doesn't always work, but in most cases it does.
The idea is to make sure you do enough iisresets and reconfigurations as possible and in different orders just to make sure you get the right one.

The steps described in the article are good, but for some reason CRM doesn't always listen to the commands you give it.

Another way to handle this is to disable the username endpoint that is causing the issue (the one with WS-Trust 1.3). This worked in one of my cases, while the first solution worked in others.

For the second solution refer to this MS KB: http://support2.microsoft.com/kb/2912175